# Reuse function from SharePoint list form

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, application-pages

I have a SharePoint 2013 list and in the `DisplayForm.aspx.cs`, I have written a function `saveastemplate()`. Now, I want to reuse the same function in an application page.

Is it possible at all, if so, how can I reuse the function in a custom application page?

Thank you.

Comment: What you mean by `My application pages`? Are you referring to settings.aspx or viewlsts.aspx and so on.. or your customized pages??

Comment: i have ribbon button (customaction) and this open a custom application page. In this application page i want to reuse the function.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a custom application page(as you mentioned in your comment) you can find it in 15 hive configured path. then you can read values from query string and do your operation in javascript function.

---

**EDIT**

If you want to reuse C# function.

1. Develop a "Class Library" project.
2. Add it in to GAC.
3. Add safecontrol entry in web.config.
4. Finally import/add the dll reference to your application pages.

> **References**: MSDN article to [create application page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231557.aspx). & Here for detailed steps to create [Class library](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/creating-C-Sharp-class-library-dll-using-visual-studio-net/).

Comment: Sorry i don't get it. could you give me an example code please

Comment: There are 2 thing you mentioned in your comment,
1. You have a common application page.
2. You have a javascript function.
So in theory you need to open the application page and place you js function. refer  for cool example..https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/28029/include-javascript-on-application-pages

Comment: Sorry its not a javascript function but its a c# function.

Comment: Updated my answer..